# Where i can look Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need to add "`MiscUtilities"` so i was searching dll `Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.dll`, where i can see this i have looked C:\Program Files

\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5 and C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies ad couldnt see where i can look

for getting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%PROGRAMFILES%\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100\\Tools\\Binn\\VSShell\\Common7\\IDE\\Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.dll
```